# Clarification on Process control block and exec command

Tags: process, operating-system, fork, exec, child-process

The Operating System notes from my university reads :

> The PCB is created when a process is born via fork, and is reclaimed
> when a process is terminated. While systems calls such as exec rewrite
> the memory image of the process, the PCB (and the entities pointed by
> it, like the kernel stack) largely remain intact during exec or any
> other system call, except for slight modifications (like changing the
> page tables to point to the new memory image).

But during fork system call, the memory image from the parent is wiped and a new memory image is initialized to the child process. Hence the PCB located in the kernel stack of the memory image is also wiped and  hence a completely new PCB is re-written to the process is my understanding.

What concept have I understood wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The process control block is located in the Kernel space in the RAM. The kernel space also has the Paging table. When he exec system command is called, the memory image of the process is wiped nd new memory image is written for the process without affecting the process control block in the kernel space for that process, but the paging table that maps the logical address and virtual address of the processes has to be changes since the memory image is changed.Hence in my knowledge,the PCB is not re-written.